# Express relations between three variables using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this

```
structure(list(cli_exp = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L), vcs_exp = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L), web_exp = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("cli_exp", "vcs_exp", 
"web_exp"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to use ggplot2 to express the relation between these three variables and tried the simple point plot

```
ggplot(data = data) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = web_exp, y = vcs_exp, color = cli_exp))
```

But apparently, there are many overlapping data points, which are not suitable for point display. Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 5):

I would use [ggpairs](https://rdrr.io/cran/GGally/man/ggpairs.html) from `GGally` package

```
tmp_df <- structure(list(cli_exp = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L), vcs_exp = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L), web_exp = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
                0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("cli_exp", "vcs_exp", 
                "web_exp"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

library(GGally)
ggpairs(tmp_df, 
    upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 10)), 
    lower = list(continuous = "smooth"))
```

[image]

Edit: use `pairs` from base R

```
pairs(tmp_df)
```

[image]

Use `pairs.panels` from `psych` package

```
library(psych)
pairs.panels(tmp_df, 
         method = "pearson",
         density = TRUE,  
         ellipses = TRUE 
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, the points overlap, so some points aren't visible when using `geom_point`.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = web_exp, y = vcs_exp, color = cli_exp)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

This can be solved by adding a small amount of jitter. Also, making the points slightly transparent will make any overlaps more clear.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = web_exp, y = vcs_exp, color = cli_exp)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0.05, alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]